# Cannot associate user role with user

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

I have a list of existing user roles in database for example like this:

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | level |   label   |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 |     0 | admin     |
|  2 |     1 | moderator |
|  3 |     2 | blogger   |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

And I would like to attach a role to a user when its created. What I've tried is following:

**In my BcUsersController:**

```
    $bcUser = $this->BcUsers->patchEntity($bcUser, $this->request->data,
        [
            'associated' => [
                'BcUserInfos',
                'BcUserRoles'
            ]
        ]
    );
    if ($this->BcUsers->save($bcUser))...
```

**Associations:**

```
//BcUserRolesTable
$this->belongsToMany('BcUsers', [
    'className' => 'BcUsers',
    'foreignKey' => 'role',
    'propertyName' => 'BcUserRoles'
]);


//BcUsersTable
$this->hasMany('BcUserRoles', [
    'className' => 'BcUserRoles',
    'foreignKey' => 'id',
    'bindingKey' => 'role',
    'propertyName' => 'BcUserRoles',
    'joinTable' => 'bc_user_roles'
]);
```

And this is how I try to inject userRoleId  into a user table:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('BcUserRoles.level', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => '0']); ?>
```

or

```
<?= $this->Form->input('BcUserRoles.id', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => '1']); ?>
```

When I try to save it gives me no error just refreshes a page and with post data inside fields. If I remove all the associations code, it saves user + userInfo. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

I just found an error in my `$bcUser` variable:

```
'[errors]' => [
        'role' => [
            '_required' => 'This field is required'
        ]
    ],
```

And I think thats why it does not save BcUser, but also userRole associations is empty:

```
'BcUserRoles' => [],
```

so it wouldnt save userRole to user table even if I would would remove

`->requirePresence('role', 'create')` from BcUsersTable, would it ?

Just tested. It throws me SQL error because role isnt in query parameters and in database it has to be there, null is not allowed. All users should have a role.

Comment: Does your BcUserRoles have an association defined with BcUsers?

Comment: @Kelvin yes it is shown in second snippet of code

Comment: did yoy read [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) paragraph from the manual? The inputs names should be `bc_user_roles.level` and `bc_user_roles.id`. Also I would follow tarikul05 suggestion

Comment: can you post an output of debug($this->request->data)

Comment: please share the users table structure for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple issues here.

**Associations**

If `BcUsersTable` contains the foreign key for `BcUserRoles` then is it a `belongsTo` relationship.

> **belongsTo**: the current model contains the foreign key.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations

Equally this would also mean that `BcUserRoles` has a `hasMany` relationship to `BcUsers` not a `belongsTo` relationship.

> **hasMany**: the other model contains the foreign key.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations

**Post data**

I assume that the foreign key for `BcUserRolesTable` in the `BcUsersTable` is `role`. That means you will need to submit a value for `role` that is the `id` of the user role you wish to associate.

The following would create a form element to do that:

`$this->Form->input('role', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $useRoleId])`

Where `$userRoleId` is the id of the role you wish to associate.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your belongsTo Relations

```
$this->belongsTo('BcUsers', [
         'className' => 'BcUsers',
         'foreignKey' => 'role',
         'bindingKey' => 'id',
         'propertyName' => 'BcUserRoles'
     ]);
```

make it

```
$this->belongsTo('BcUserRoles', [
         'className' => 'BcUsers',
         'foreignKey' => 'role',
         'bindingKey' => 'id',
     ]);
```

Hope your problem will be solved

Comment: You should clear concept on cakephp relationship, for removing error just use `$this->Form->input('role', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => 0])`

Comment: sorry it should be  `$this->Form->input('BcUserRoles._ids', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => [0,1]])` for admin and moderator type user